# PyQt4 loading new UI files to one main window

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4

I want to create a functionality for a program that I am writing and I have a main window that has 4 buttons.

I want it to change the current main UI to some other sub-window.
For example, if you click the "Settings" button, I want my main UI to change to a UI that represents the "Settings" section of my program.

How do I do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try creating another UI, and when one of the buttons is pressed on the main UI, create an instance of that UI. For instance, if "settings" is clicked, it would create an instance of the SettingsUI class, which would be similar to your main UI.

Another option you have is to use a QTabWidget and personalize the tabs and what they contain.